# *Diagonal* section in a cone (the section should be an *Ellipse*); but actually a *Circle* how come?!

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

In the picture you see an oblique cone with two sections through it ($AB$ and $CD$ segments).

I computed the semi-major and semi-minor axes and both of them were $\dfrac{rh^3}{l^3}$ in the $AB$ case. so this is in fact a circle?

Also, in the $CD$ case, the semi-major axis is longer than $AB$ case; but its semi-minor axis is obviously $\dfrac{rh^3}{l^3}$ again. so it is an ellipse.[image]

Comment: How can the axes of $AB$ possibly be independent of the position of  $AB$? (Also, should your $2r$ perhaps be $r$?)

Comment: from $E$ to the right vertex is a complete circle. so it is actually $2r$. I didn't get your first question

Comment: So it's not a right cone.

Comment: It is. the segment from $E$ to the upper vertex is perpendicular to the circle's diameter

Comment: That is not what [right cone](https://www.mathwords.com/r/right_cone.htm) means. The apex of the cone has to be above the _centre_ of the base. The usual facts about conic sections apply only to right circular cones, which this is not.

Comment: $AB$ is the semi-major axis itself; it isn't independent of the position of $AB$. it is equal to $\frac{rh^3}{l^3}$ using Pythagorean rule and Thales' theorem. Also, the semi-minor axis is again $\frac{rh^3}{l^3}$; because its formula is $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{BC*AD}$. first find $BC$ and $AD$ like $AB$. I forgot to indicate: $AB$ and $DE$ are perpendicular to $l$.

Comment: so what would be applied to my cone? (so it is oblique)

Comment: First of all, when asking for help, it's rude to write with big letters and use '?!'. Please, write down everything you had in your mind because it is chaotic. You're the one who should show effort, not the other members  in order to read your mind and consider everything you forgot to indicate and ponder because you hadn't checked what the words you used mean before posting.

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya I think you're overthinking. I used the Capital letters just to indicate my excitement and emphasizing on the words. not other reasons. Also I don't know why you call using "?!" as rude! it is also just for showing both question and that I am surprised

Comment: The figure is missing several markers that would have said something about the angles and might have enabled someone to deduce the same axis lengths that you did. Those of us who have seen some of your other questions might be able to guess what the missing markers should have been, but in general you should try to write a question in such a way that it can be fully understood by itself.

Comment: @DavidK it was an oblique cone. I mistakenly wrote "right".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have an oblique circular cone like this one
(and it *is* an oblique circular cone, since the axis--then line from the vertex to the center of the circular base--is not perpendicular to the base),
all planes parallel to the base (such as the ones that cut the cone along $AD$ and  $BC$) intersect the cone in circles;
but there is also another family of planes whose intersections with the cone also are circles.

You have found one of that other set of planes for your particular cone.